# cocoa: How to make background transparent webView？

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

The mac osx ，I want to make my webview to look transparent and show the data on it with background showing images of parent view.

Can anyone please let me know how to do this?
This method can not

```
NSString * source = @"<html><head><title></title></head><body><div id=\"box\">Example Box</div></body></html>";
[[webView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:source baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""] ];
[[webView windowScriptObject] evaluateWebScript:@"document.getElementById('box').style.backgroundColor = '#dddddd';"]; // Change box background
[[webView windowScriptObject] evaluateWebScript:@"document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#dddddd';"]; // Change body background
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, you're setting the background color of the page in your web view to an opaque color. That's not going to work, is it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to call `setDrawsBackground:` on the `WebView` and pass in `NO`. That will prevent the web view from drawing a background unless the page loaded in the web view explicitly sets the background color.

Answer (score -1):

We can add background image in WebView using cocoa. to do this we need to add css for body tag.

**Create a webview:**

```
WebView *webView;
```

**Fetch image form bundle path:**

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"my-bg" ofType:@"jpg"];
```

**write Css for body tag.**

```
NSMutableString *htmlBuilder = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[htmlBuilder appendString:@"body {"];
[htmlBuilder appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" background-image: url('file://%@');",path]];
[htmlBuilder appendString:@"}"];
```

**Load this image on webview**

```
[[webView mainFrame] loadHTMLString:htmlBuilder baseURL:nil];
[webView setDrawsBackground:NO];
```

Your image will be added in background on webview.